# Vaadin 8 using an image as a button. Doesn't fire click event

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I'm building a Vaadin 8 app ( first one for me ).  I am using the designer to generate the UI.  I've added several buttons to the dashboard which should fire a function when clicked.  For some reason nothing fires when the image is clicked. Below is all the code that is involved.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code from the .html file:

```
<vaadin-horizontal-layout responsive width-full margin>
    **<vaadin-image icon="theme://images/properties.png" style-name="my-image-button" responsive alt="" _id="imagePropertyInfo"></vaadin-image>**
    <vaadin-image icon="theme://images/occupants.png" responsive alt="" _id="imageOccupants"></vaadin-image>
    <vaadin-image icon="theme://images/vendors.png" responsive alt="" _id="imageVendors"></vaadin-image>
   </vaadin-horizontal-layout>
```

Here is the scss
      .my-image-button
      {
        cursor: pointer;
      }

Here is the code from the Dashboard UI
    public DashboardHomeView( OnCallUI onCallUI )
        {
            this.onCallUI = onCallUI;

```
        // Make it disabled until a property is selected
        **imagePropertyInfo.setEnabled( false );
        imagePropertyInfo.setStyleName( "my-image-button" );**
        fetchPropertyBasicInfo();
    }

    protected void fetchPropertyBasicInfo()
    {
        List<PropertyProfileBasic> listOfPropertyProfiles = new ArrayList<PropertyProfileBasic>( OnCallUI.myStarService.fetchAllPropertyProfileBasicInformation() );
        comboBoxGeneric.setCaption( "Select a Property" );
        comboBoxGeneric.setItemCaptionGenerator( aProperty -> aProperty.toString() );
        comboBoxGeneric.setItems( listOfPropertyProfiles );
        comboBoxGeneric.addValueChangeListener( event -> fetchOccupantBasicInfo( event ) );
        comboBoxGeneric.focus();
    }

    protected void fetchOccupantBasicInfo( ValueChangeEvent<PropertyProfileBasic> event )
    {
        // Fetch all the occupants for the selected property
        if( event.getValue().getPropertyNo() != null )
        {
            //  Fetch a list of occupant basic info for the selected property
            List<OccupantProfileBasic> listOfOccupantProfiles = new ArrayList<OccupantProfileBasic>( OnCallUI.myStarService.fetchOccupantProfileBasicByPropertyNo( event.getValue().getPropertyNo() ) );
            //  Clear the existing grid et al
            gridContainer.removeAllComponents();
            //  Add the occupant grid
            occupantGrid = new OccupantProfileBasicGrid( listOfOccupantProfiles );
            //  Show the grid
            gridContainer.addComponents( new Label( "Occupants" ), occupantGrid );

            //  Set the dashboard buttons to enabled now a property is selected
            **imagePropertyInfo.setEnabled( true );
            // Add the property info button
            imagePropertyInfo.addClickListener( e -> fetchPropertyInformation() );**
        }
    }

    protected void fetchPropertyInformation()
    {
        Notification.show( "Yo!", "You clicked!", Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using GridLayout. I am recommending another approach. Use Button, and set the button style to be borderless (apparently you want something like that. The icon of the button can be image from your theme, using ThemeResource. "Pseudo code" is something like this:

```
ThemeResource icon = new ThemeResource("/images/properties.png");
Button imagePropertyInfo = new Button(icon);
imagePropertyInfo.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_BORDERLESS);
imagePropertyInfo.addClickListener( e -> fetchPropertyInformation() );
```

Note also, JavaDoc of Image component says.

"public Registration addClickListener(MouseEvents.ClickListener listener)
Add a click listener to the component. The listener is called whenever the user clicks inside the component. Depending on the content the event may be blocked and in that case no event is fired."

I think it does not like your way of setting image with theme, without using Resource.

If you want to remove the focus highlight of the button, it should be possible via this CSS rule:

```
.v-button-link:after {
  content: none;
}
```

Also it is worth of mentioning that Image is not Focusable, while Button is. This means that even that Image can have click listener, it is not reached by keyboard navigation, Button is Focusable and is reached by tabbing etc. So using Button instead of Image makes your application more accessible.

Comment: This is actually three images on a page not in a grid....  I'm using Vaadin designer for the UI thus it's generating the html and java files. I did use a button before but it looked terrible when I went to click on it, it had a strange box below the image.

Isn't it possible to add a click listener to an image?  This should be fairly basic one would think.

Comment: Figured it out.  I changed the main style name from v-button to borderless.  The only bummer is it doesn't show gray when it's disabled as the v-button does.  However, v-button shows an ugly rectangle over the image.  I tried adding borderless as an additional style name but didn't help.

Comment: @Bitwyse1 Thanks for  your comments, I refined my answer to address these.